# How to get access of data from multiple key in two or more depth without looping

Tags: redis

I am using redis for get data from server.

I am creating stream for following which is having structure like this

```
Sadd user_following_key user1_id, user2_id, user3_id
#data which i want to access is stored like this
zadd user1_id_key  data1
zadd user2_id_key data2 
#And data1 data2 ... are set which is stored like this
Set data1 some_data
set data2 some_data
```

I want to access data1 data2 ... and some_data without running loop over user_following_key return data and also if two or more key are same then only one should come.

Comment: May be sadd user2_id_key data<X>?

Comment: It is already stored the way i told . And i want to access info

Answer (score 1):

Put differently, for each `user_id` in `user_following_key`, you want to access the relevant `user_id` key, retrieve the `data` key name from it and then fetch the value of the `data` key. In that case, you must loop over the contents of `user_following_key` (and over every multi-valued key) in this dereference chain and have multiple calls, per depth/length.

**Note:** in similar cases Lua could be used to reduce network traffic and latency, but since you'll be actually programmatically dealing with key names inside the script (i.e.g. `user_id1`), it will make the script unsafe in terms of Redis cluster and against best practices.

Comment: It is already stored the way i told . And i want to access info so i want to access without loop and the one u r telling will run loop

Comment: You'll have to store data differently then - flatten everything and just do a single read.